# Rails: How to troubleshoot cookies that won't expire?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, cookies, session-cookies

Followed, for the most part, [Railscast #274 - Remember Me](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password) to set a **remember me token** in my Rails app and although cookies are "working" there seems to be no difference between `cookies.permanent[…] = …` and `cookies[…] = …`.

The weird thing is that examining the cookies in **Chrome** and **Safari** (all I've tested thus far) show them Expiring on "Browser close" and with the "Session" respectively. But I can verify that quitting and relaunching the site will persist the cookie and the user remains logged in!?! So, it would seem, something else is going on…

I don't even know where to begin troubleshooting this and don't have much experience with Rails cookies and/or sessions that are misbehaving. **Any ideas?**

Here's some code FWIW:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    if params[:remember_me]
      cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
      self.current_user = user
    else
      cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    end
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token!(cookies[:remember_token]) if cookies[:remember_token]
  end
  ...
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new

  end

  def create
    user = User.where('lower(email) = ?', params[:email].downcase).first
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user 
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting with this today and it happens not to be Rails related but Chrome's (I guess Opera as well). Since Chrome's version 19, when the option **continue where I left off** is set, they don't follow the [standard (section 4.3.1)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109) and don't delete any cookies on browser close. So the remember me feature doesn't work as expected because you would expect the non-permanent cookie to be deleted when you close the browser. This is the chromium bug with WontFix status: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128513

In my case (might be yours as well), the situation was even more weird because I don't use the *continue where I left off* option and still Chrome was not deleting cookies on browser close. After finding [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128567) other bug, I realized that it was actually the option **Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed** preventing those cookies from being removed. I don't know/remember how that option got enabled in my browser or whether it is now the default behaviour...

Anyways, my remember_me checkbox is working as expected now. Hope your's got fixed too and if it didn't at least this will help you.